# What is the difference?

Tags: javascript

1ST CODE VARIANT:

```js
let getLastDayOfMonth = function(year, month) {
  let date = new Date();
  date.setFullYear(year, month, 28);
  while (date.getMonth() === month){
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  return date.getDate();
};
    
alert(getLastDayOfMonth(2012, 1)); //29
```

2ND CODE VARIANT:

```js
let getLastDayOfMonth = function(year, month) {
    let date = new Date();
    date.setFullYear(year);
    date.setMonth(month);
    date.setDate(28);
    while (date.getMonth() === month){
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
    return date.getDate();
};
alert(getLastDayOfMonth(2012, 1)); //not correctly
```

THE QUESTION:
Why does the 1st code work correctly but the second doesn't alert correct day (if the month number = 1 it becomes March not Feb and idk why). Thanks!

Comment: You can set the month to the next month and the day-of-month to 0, it's much easier

Comment: I got it but I don't understand what is the difference between 2 my codes

Comment: Depends on what date you call the function. Try alert on date.getMonth() just after you set it. At the moment (last 2 days of March) the day is >28 so the month goes from 1 to 2 as Feb only had 29 days in 2012.  Try your code on Monday and you wont have a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is, when you do

```
var date = new Date();
```

Then date has the value of the current day (at the time of my posting it's the 2024-03-30). When you now do

```
date.setMonth(month);
```

with `month === 1` it will try to set the month to February, but as there is no Feb 30th, with the `Date`'s internal overflow logic `date` will become Mar 1st (because 2012 is a leap year, it would become Mar 2nd in a non-leap year).

Then you do

```
date.setDay(28);
```

which will set `date` to be Mar 28th.

But your while loop will then not be executed, because `month === getMonth()` does not evaluate to `true`

Finally, you again substract one day, which leaves you with Mar 27th, and that's the output you get. So to conclude, this snippet will work for the 1st to 28th (and 29th in leap years) of each month, but not with the 30th or 31st

When you do it like in your first snippet

```
date.setFullYear(year, month, 28);
```

(with `month === 1`) it will set date to be Feb 28th, thus your code will work.

BTW you could just do

```
let date = new Date(year, month, 28);
```